# Errors with matplotlib and numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

i am trying to learn using matplotlib and to do so i installed Anaconda3 and VSCode. With anaconda3 all the required libraries are installed, but when i try running a simple code i get a bunch of errors.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

fruits = \['apple', 'blueberry', 'cherry', 'orange'\]
counts = \[40, 100, 30, 55\]
bar_labels = \['red', 'blue', '\_red', 'orange'\]
bar_colors = \['tab:red', 'tab:blue', 'tab:red', 'tab:orange'\]

ax.bar(fruits, counts, label=bar_labels, color=bar_colors)

ax.set_ylabel('fruit supply')
ax.set_title('Fruit supply by kind and color')
ax.legend(title='Fruit color')

plt.show()
```

this is a simple code i found online and i tried running it to see if everything worked correctly but i get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\ahmed\Desktop\saved\mat1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Users\ahmed\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 104, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "C:\Users\ahmed\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 150, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "C:\Users\ahmed\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 70, in <module>
    from . import numerictypes as nt
  File "C:\Users\ahmed\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numerictypes.py", line 596, in <module>
    _register_types()
  File "C:\Users\ahmed\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numerictypes.py", line 591, in _register_types
    numbers.Integral.register(integer)
AttributeError: module 'numbers' has no attribute 'Integral'
```

and the errors are: [errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8T7F.png)
I'm new to all this so i don't really know what to do

Comment: What version of numpy and matplotlib are you using?

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: matplot lib: 3.5.2, numpy: 1.21.5, Python: 3.9.13

Comment: Within Python, can you just to just `import numbers`? Then, on the Python prompt (or in the script), `print(numbers.__file__)`.

Comment: Do you happen to have a file named `numbers.py` lying around?

Comment: Yoooo thank you guys very much, i had a numbers.py file in the same directory and i totally forgot, now it works perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `numbers.py` file in your working directory. Rename or remove it, so that Python (and NumPy) will be pick up the correct `numbers` module from the standard library.

Answer (score -1):

I think there is some issue inside the libraries on your pc.

I have checked the code by myself and it is working fine from my side.

Also, I think there are some backspaces inside the code which are not necessary.
Update this lines of code by my code :

```
fruits = \['apple', 'blueberry', 'cherry', 'orange'\]
counts = \[40, 100, 30, 55\]
bar_labels = \['red', 'blue', '\_red', 'orange'\]
bar_colors = \['tab:red', 'tab:blue', 'tab:red', 'tab:orange'\]
```

Updated code with live result is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

fruits = ['apple', 'blueberry', 'cherry', 'orange']
counts = [40, 100, 30, 55]
bar_labels = ['red', 'blue', 'red', 'orange']
bar_colors = ['tab:red', 'tab:blue', 'tab:red', 'tab:orange']

ax.bar(fruits, counts, label=bar_labels, color=bar_colors)

ax.set_ylabel('fruit supply')
ax.set_title('Fruit supply by kind and color')
ax.legend(title='Fruit color')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: okay, do you know what kind of issues it could be?

Comment: It could be a python libraries versions issue. It will work fine on Google Colab.

Comment: okay thank you, i'm going to use that until i solved the proble then

Comment: If you find it useful then mark it as the right answer for other people. Thank you.